# How can I read Float from Core Data / iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-data, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ipad

I have Float values stored in Core-Data.
What is the code to use to read these values in an NSstring ?

Answer (score 5):

Core-Data uses NSNumber objects to store the float value.

To get the 'raw' float value and put it into a string you would use something like this.

```
NSNumber *floatNumber = [managedObject valueForKey:@"myFloatValueKey"];
float myFloat = [floatNumber floatValue];
NSString *floatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", myFloat];
```

Maybe a NSNumberFormatter would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that you mean your Core Data *entity* has an attribute of type float, you could simply access that field after you perform a fetch of that object.

```
[[self managedObjectContext] fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"EntityName" withPredicate:
@"(attribute LIKE[c] 'value') AND (attribute2 > %@)", someValue];
```

You could then put this in string format with this:

```
NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[managedObject floatAttribute] floatVal]];
```